# How do I write the HQL to query the many to many?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have the User model and the the system allows users to follow each other.
So I put two lists in the User model as below：

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "t_user_t_followingUser", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "followingUser_id") })
public List<User> getFollowingUsers() {
    return followingUsers;
}

public void setFollowingUsers(List<User> followingUsers) {
    this.followingUsers = followingUsers;
}

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "t_user_t_followedUser", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "followedUser_id") })
public List<User> getFollowedUsers() {
    return followedUsers;
}

public void setFollowedUsers(List<User> followedUsers) {
    this.followedUsers = followedUsers;
}
```

And now I want to get the total followers of the user u.
How to write the HQL?

ps: The many2many may be not proper.And any suggestion to the design?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How you tried to write you query?

Comment: "select count(*) from User u left join u.followedUsers where u = ?"seems like work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `SELECT COUNT(fu) FROM User AS u INNER JOIN u.followedUsers AS fu;`